# Is this equality obvious? ("Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, permutations, tensors

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

I can prove the following equality, but is it obvious?

> $$\text{Alt}(T)(v_1,\dots,v_j,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)\\=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn }\sigma\cdot T(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(j)},\dots,v_{\sigma(i)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)}).$$

My proof of the above equality is here (I used Theorem 4-3(1).):

> $$
> \text{Alt}(T)(v_1,\dots,v_j,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)\\=
> -\text{Alt}(T)(v_1,\dots,v_k)
> \\=
> \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}-\text{sgn }\sigma'\cdot T(v_{\sigma'(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma'(k)})
> \\=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn }\sigma\cdot T(v_{\sigma'(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma'(i)},\dots,v_{\sigma'(j)},\dots, v_{\sigma'(k)})
> \\=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn }\sigma\cdot T(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(j)},\dots,v_{\sigma(i)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)}).
> $$

My proof of Theorem 4-3(1) is as follows:

Let $\sigma_1:=(i,j)$.

$$\text{Alt}(T)(v_1,\dots,v_j,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)\\=\text{Alt}(T)(v_{\sigma_1(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(i)},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(j)},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(k)})
\\=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn }\sigma\cdot T(v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(1))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(i))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(j))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(k))})\\=
\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn }\sigma_1\cdot\text{sgn }(\sigma_1\circ\sigma)\cdot T(v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(1))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(i))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(j))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(k))})
\\=-\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn }(\sigma_1\circ\sigma)\cdot T(v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(1))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(i))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(j))},\dots,v_{\sigma_1(\sigma(k))})
\\=-\text{Alt}(T)(v_1,\dots,v_k).
$$

[image]